# How to retain in app Locale change after orientation change

Tags: android, locale, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I am able to change Locale within the application, but once the orientation changes the app resources are reloaded with the default system language.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code... just call the same code that changed the location from onCreate()